# Send email by C# from my website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sendmail

i use the following code to send email :

```
        public static bool SendEmail(string To, string ToName, string From, string FromName, string Subject, string Body, bool IsBodyHTML)
        {
            try
            {
                MailAddress FromAddr = new MailAddress(From, FromName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                MailAddress ToAddr = new MailAddress(To, ToName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                var smtp = new SmtpClient
                {
                    Host = "smtp.datagts.net",
                    Port = 587,
                    EnableSsl = false,
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = true,                                        
                    Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("MeEmail@...", "Password")
                };

                using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage(FromAddr, ToAddr)
                {
                    Subject = Subject,
                    Body = Body,                    
                    IsBodyHtml = IsBodyHTML,                    
                    BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,                   

                })
                {
                    smtp.Send(message);
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

It works on local and when i use my web site under my local IIS but when i upload it to my website it does not work and does not send email even any error occurs.

is there anybody out there to help me about this ?

**UPDATE1** : i remove the try catch and catch an error with this message : `Failure sending mail`

**UPDATE2** : I change my stmp server and use my Gmail account , look at this code :

```
public static bool SendEmail(string To, string ToName, string From, string FromName, string Subject, string Body, bool IsBodyHTML)
            {
                try
                {
                    MailAddress FromAddr = new MailAddress(From, FromName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                    MailAddress ToAddr = new MailAddress(To, ToName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                    var smtp = new SmtpClient
                    {
                        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                        Port = 587,
                        EnableSsl = true,
                        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                        UseDefaultCredentials = false,                                        
                        Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("MeEmail@gmail.com", "Password")
                    };

                    using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage(FromAddr, ToAddr)
                    {
                        Subject = Subject,
                        Body = Body,                    
                        IsBodyHtml = IsBodyHTML,                    
                        BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,                   

                    })
                    {
                        smtp.Send(message);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

and now i get an error yet :(

I get the **"MustIssueStartTlsFirst"** error that mentioned in this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpstatuscode.aspx). 
I am now trying to check @EdFS point and use port 25

**UPDATE3**: It is because i use the shared server , i just can change the port to 25 , and steel it does not work an give the same error, I am trying to get support from my server backup team

Comment: Is your website configured differently than your local machine?

Comment: Is a firewall blocking outgoing traffic to Port 587?

Comment: Try removing the try/catch and see what exception is thrown; if that doesn't help, post the exception details here so we can all see what the real problem is.

Comment: @DanielRenshaw , ok , i will update it my q as soon as possible

Comment: @Ali is there no information besides "Failure sending mail"? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc.aspx suggests 5 types of exceptions might be thrown; which was it?

Comment: @DanielRenshaw , just one detail and it is about 4th error listed in MSDN page you linked : "SmtpException"

Comment: @Ali Ok, then there is other information to be found, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpexception.aspx For example, the `StatusCode` property will give you the SMTP server's error code which can be looked up in a suitable reference... assuming it's getting as far as connecting to the SMTP server.

Comment: We need to see all the exception details please? More.Info.Needed. Could be a firewall port blocked, the server ip is blacklisted, etc.

Comment: @DanielRenshaw , so i found that the statuscode is "GeneralFailure" that depend on what i read on MSDN , it is not possbile ,if the specified SMTP host cannot be found so it can not be found on the local . how is it possible ?!!

Comment: @Pure.Krome , ok will update my q now

Comment: Plz post stack trace, and check if there is any inner exception

Comment: @AliForoughi - u haven't posted any stack track info....

Comment: Any final solution with full source code sample about it ?

Answer (score 5):

**Assuming** the SMTP server (smtp.datagts.net) is running fine, some items to check:

1. Your code seems to be using `UseDefaultCredentials=true`, but on the next line your are providing credentials
2. As mentioned in the comments check that Port 587 isn't blocked at your web host
3. If you are hosted on a shared server (not a dedicated machine), it's *likely* ASP.Net is set for `medium trust`. **IF** so, you [cannot use any port for SMTP *other* than **Port 25**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alvar/archive/2010/02/08/smtp-problems-when-asp-net-is-not-running-in-full-trust.aspx).

---

Update:

To try and get to the error. In your **LOCAL** (development) machine, add this to your web.config:

```
<system.web>
...
    <securityPolicy>
      <trustLevel name="Medium" />
    </securityPolicy>
...
```

ASP.Net on your local machine runs in `FULL TRUST`. The above setting makes the current web site/application you are working on run in `medium trust`. You can remove/comment as necessary. The point of this exercise is to *try* and match what your web host settings are (it's obviously different if things work in your local machine then dies when published). It would be nice to just obtain the info from your web host..but until then....

Then try both Port 587 and 25.

- It should fail on port 587 with a security exception (because of `medium trust`)
- If your mail server *only* accepts SMTP connections on port 587, then of course, port 25 will not work either (but you should get a different error). The point being *"...it still doesn't work..."* in this case is that the SMTP server (smtp.datagts.net) *only* accepts connections on port 587

GMAIL is the same story. You cannot use Port 587 if your web host settings for ASP.Net is `medium trust`. I have been through this many times - it will "work" in my local machine, but as soon as I enable `medium trust` in my local development machine, it will fail.

You should ask your web host what their settings are for ASP.Net - if its some "custom" setting you can ask for a copy and use that in your dev box as well.

Comment: @AntonioBakula - yup, its one of those gotchas. These days, if the site I'm developing isn't going to a dedicated box, my VS settings are set to medium trust during development (or ask the host for their settings and match them locally).

Comment: Wow! never knew about the Medium Trust + port 25 -only-.