# Send email from my asp.net site uploaded on a shared server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sendmail

What are needed to send an email from my asp.net site? this question asked because I have a site for sending email , it works correct in local machine , but when i uploaded it on a shared server it does not work and give me this error : **Failure sending mail**

now i have some question about this problem :

1 - Is it SSL always required to send an email by SMTP?
2 - what about the first question if i use my gmail account?
3 - is there some configuration on my host PleskPanel to send email ?
4 - after contact with my host support team they said me that my code has problem , but i know my code is correct , here is my code

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.EnableSsl = false;
client.Host = "smtp.datagts.net";
client.Port = 587; // setup Smtp authentication    
System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@datagts.net","*****");
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = credentials;
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.From = new MailAddress("info@datagts.net");
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("foroughi.ali@gmail.com"));
msg.Subject = "Test";
msg.IsBodyHtml = false;
msg.Body = "Body is here";
client.Send(msg);
```

**Note** : for more info about my problem i asked another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10563397/985084) about this issue that i have not get any correct answer

Comment: I don't know why your code isn't working; but I can say that some providers do allow non-SSL for SMTP.  I also know you can use your Gmail account (there are lots of examples of this online: http://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/csharp.aspx?cat=2).  But I haven't run into any problems before.  Given that it works on your machine, it does seem to suggest a configuration issue.

Comment: This is a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10563397/304683), don't create a new one.

Comment: @EdSF ,Realy?where did you find out?!! hahaha. from the link i put in my question? Look at the contents , no this is not a duplicate question , at the previous question i am looking for a wrong thing in my code , and if you open your eye you will see that in this question i am looking for some configuration on my host , so these question are different clearly.