# Unable to send mail from ASP.NET web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I have a Contact Us page in my website from which I am trying to send mail.Here is my code
MailMessage feedBack = new MailMessage();

```
feedBack.To.Add("some@some.com");
feedBack.From = new MailAddress("MyClient@some.com");
feedBack.Subject = "Mail from My Client's Website.";  
feedBack.Body = "Sender Name: " + Name.Text + "<br/><br/>Sender Last Name:"+LastName.Text+"<br/><br/>Sender Company:"+Company.Text+"<br/><br/>Sender Designation:"+Designation.Text+"<br/><br/>Sender Email:"+Email.Text+"<br/><br/>Sender Phone No:"+ PhoneNo.Text+"<br/><br/>Sender Enquiry:"+Enquiry.Text;
feedBack.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "smtp.MyClient.com"; //Or Your SMTP Server Address
//smtp.Port = 25;
//smtp.EnableSsl =false;
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("MyClient@some.com","XXXX");
//Or your Smtp Email ID and Password
 smtp.Send(feedBack);
```

All the time I keep getting this error

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 64.37.118.141:25

I have verified with my client and all the details are correct(`smtp server name,credentials`).

I also tried setting port to 587 and 465 but it did not work.

Can someone help me out with this?

What can be the cause?

I am not able to find it.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: try sending to your own personal email (like yahoo or gmail and see if you get the same error)

Comment: Who is your provider? Maybe they have a relay sever that you need to use.

Comment: @AlexMendez I have not asked about it , they gave me POP server and SMTP server name.

Comment: @DotNetRookie Currently I am trying to send it to my own gmail account.

Comment: @freebird Please try with smtp.EnableSsl = true;

Comment: @HatSoft I got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the ip above with port 25 through telnet and got the following response:

Command:

```
telnet 64.37.118.141 25
```

Response:

```
Could not open connection to the host, on port 25: Connect failed
```

Most likely port 25 is being blocked. You will need to find what port is used with your pop/smtp servers.

Comment: Should I ask them the port no for the smtp server.

Comment: Most of the time they have it listed in their FAQ. You should be able to find it on their site or you can call and ask for it.

Comment: Thanks for the help.So do you think the problem might be with the port no.

Comment: It is a posiblility. Most providers now block certain ports as a security measure. Port 25 being one of them.

Comment: I had the same problem as you and found that using the same configurations that they provide for programs like MS Outlook, also worked for .net.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I will ask for the port no.Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

### MEDIUM TRUST

If you are on a shared hosting service, *chances are* that ASP.Net is set to run in `medium-trust` (as it should). This restricts SMTP to port 25 **only**, you cannot use any other port.

- [SMTP problems when ASP.NET is not running in full-trust](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alvar/archive/2010/02/08/smtp-problems-when-asp-net-is-not-running-in-full-trust.aspx)
- [SO similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10563397/304683)

Comment: So what do you recommend EdSF , can you just brief me about my chances I am a bit clueless here.Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @freebird Clarification needed - whose SMTP server are you using to send mail? You provided an IP above, but in some of the comments you mention GMAIL?

Comment: I am using my clients SMTP server.

Comment: @freebird If you are using your client's server, then see the above answer by Alex. It seems Port 25 is blocked. If they use a different port **and** the web site is hosted on a shared server, then you will run into issues (again, you can only use Port 25 in `medium trust`). Solutions: ask your client why port 25 is blocked, what port should be used. Find out what your hosting options are - shared will almost always mean `medium trust`, and if so use a different SMTP server....

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the server that the web application resides on is set up to be allowed to send mail through the SMTP server?  Trust connections sometimes have to be setup to allow relaying off one server throught another.

Comment: Should I ask them if the given smtp server is permitted to send emails?